# if subset $A$ is dense in $S$, and if $S$ is dense in $T$ then to prove that $A$ is dense in $T$ (check logic)

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Let $x$ be a point in $T$. Because $S$ is a dense in $T$, then we consider two cases:

- $x \in S$: Because $A$ is dense in $S$, then $x \in A$ or $x$ is a limit point of A. That is definition of dense.
- $x \in S'$: then we have $A \bigcup A' \subseteq S \bigcup S'$(This is problematic part). then $x \in A$ or $x$ is a limit point of A. That is definition of dense.

Is this proof ok or there are mistakes in it? Because I am not very sure if I did the second part correctly

Comment: "$x$ is a limit point of $A$" in $S$, but also in $T$? true, but it might need a proof. Do you take $A'$ always in $T$ ? (as to the second part)?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma if $A'$ is in $T$, than my conclusion is true. But if not, I have a problem in my proof. How can I fix it?

Comment: Just use closures (as I did): $\overline{A} = A \cup A'$ and use that $\overline{\overline{A}} = \overline{A}$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thank you:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A$ is dense in $S$ (in the subspace topology) can be written as (all closures in $T$)

$$S = \overline{A} \cap S \implies S \subseteq \overline{A}$$

while $S$ dense in $T$ just means $\overline{S}  =T$.

So we have

$$S \subseteq \overline{A} \implies T = \overline{S} \subseteq \overline{\overline{A}}= \overline{A} \implies \overline{A}  =T$$

showing that $A$ is dense as well.

Comment: yes you are right..i had to consider the subspace topolgy

Answer (score 3):

Better(?): Let $U\subseteq T$ be a nonempty open set. You want to show that $U\cap A\ne\emptyset$.
As $S$ is dense in $T$, you know that there exists $U\cap S\ne\emptyset$. Thus $U\cap S$ is a nonempty open set of the space $S$. As $A$ is dense in $S$, $(U\cap S)\cap A\ne \emptyset$, and so $U\cap A\neq\emptyset$.

Comment: It's nicer, thank you:)
But can you leave comments about my proof? Is it correct? If yes, is it cleare enough or should I correct something? If my proof is wrong, where I did a mistake?

Comment: That is a proof for metric spaces to a problem that was not limited to metric spaces.

Comment: @yef_dan_92 With your method, you need to rely upon (i.e., know and mention) that limit points of limit points are limit points. Then you are fine

Comment: @WilliamElliot When I wrote it, the problem *was* limited to metric spaces.